# Getting "TypeError: cannot read classList of undefined" for FAQ toggle in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I alter this JS so it works inside of a react component? When I add an onClick handler to the span button I get "cannot read property classList of undefined". This was JS taken out of a non react project so I understand that I'm probably not doing this as best practice, but need the direction to make it work.

Here is my code.

```html
import React from "react"

const Faq = () => {

  const toggleFAQ = function(question) {
    if( question.parentElement.classList.contains('is-opened') ) {
      question.parentElement.classList.remove('is-opened');
    } else {
      question.parentElement.classList.add('is-opened');
    }
  }
  if( document.querySelector('.faq') !== null ) {
    const questions = Array.from( document.getElementsByClassName('faq__question') );
  
    questions[0].parentElement.classList.add('is-opened');
  
    questions.forEach((question) => {
      question.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleFAQ(question));
    })
  }
 
  return (
    <>
      <section className="faq">
        <div className="faq__inner">
          <h2 className="faq__title">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
          <ul className="faq__list">
            <li className="faq__item">
              <h3 className="faq__question">
                How do I make this work?
                <span className="faq__question-btn" onClick={toggleFAQ}></span>
              </h3>
              <article className="faq__answer is-opened">
                <div className="faq__answer-inner is-opened">
                  <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum
                  </p>
                </div>
              </article>
            </li>
            <li className="faq__item">
              <h3 className="faq__question">
                Help me, Lord?
                <span className="faq__question-btn"></span>
              </h3>
              <article className="faq__answer">
                <div className="faq__answer-inner">
                  <p>
                    You suck at JS
                  </p>
                </div>
              </article>
            </li>
            <li className="faq__item">
              <h3 className="faq__question">
                How does this work. Help?
                <span className="faq__question-btn"></span>
              </h3>
              <article className="faq__answer">
                <div className="faq__answer-inner">
                  <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </article>
            </li>
            <li className="faq__item">
              <h3 className="faq__question">
                Lorem Ipsum?
                <span className="faq__question-btn"></span>
              </h3>
              <article className="faq__answer">
                <div className="faq__answer-inner">
                  <p>
                    Lorem ipsum
                  </p>
                </div>
              </article>
            </li>
            <li className="faq__item">
              <h3 className="faq__question">
                Lorem Ipsum?
                <span className="faq__question-btn"></span>
              </h3>
              <article className="faq__answer">
                <div className="faq__answer-inner">
                  <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum
                  </p>
                </div>
              </article>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}
export default Faq
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Other than you shouldn't query the DOM directly or mutate it in react, can you be more specific about which `classList` is being accessed, and include a set of reproduction steps?

Comment: The first argument that is going to be passed to `toggleFAQ` is the `SyntheticEvent` object passed by react, so `question` is not going to be your element hence why you get the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, you don't manipulate the DOM and classLists directly like you are doing / would do in vanilla JS. Instead, it's better to store some state, manipulate the state and then render your view based on the data.

So, I would probably do something like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Faq = () => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
    { id: 1, title: 'How do I make this work?', content: 'Lorem Ipsum', isOpen: true },
    { id: 2, title: 'Help me, Lord?', content: 'You suck at JS', isOpen: false },
    { id: 3, title: 'How does this work. Help?', content: 'Lorem Ipsum.', isOpen: false },
    { id: 4, title: 'Lorem Ipsum?', content: 'Lorem ipsum', isOpen: false },
    { id: 5, title: 'Lorem Ipsum?', content: 'Lorem ipsum', isOpen: false },
  ])

  const toggleFAQ = (questionId) => () => {
    const newQuestions = [
      ...questions,
    ]
    const questionIndex = questions.findIndex(q => q.id === questionId)
    newQuestions[questionIndex].isOpen = !newQuestions[questionIndex].isOpen
    setQuestions(newQuestions)
  }
 
  return (
    <section className="faq">
      <div className="faq__inner">
        <h2 className="faq__title">Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
        <ul className="faq__list">
          {questions.map(q => (
            <li key={q.id} className="faq__item">
              <h3 className="faq__question">
                {q.title}
                <span className="faq__question-btn" onClick={toggleFAQ(q.id)}></span>
              </h3>
              <article className={`faq__answer ${q.isOpen ? 'is-opened' : ''}`}>
                <div className={`faq__answer-inner ${q.isOpen ? 'is-opened' : ''}`}>
                  <p>
                    {q.content}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </article>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Faq
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is exactly what I'm looking for using useState. I'm just unable to get the onClick to open anything. I'm guessing that has to do with the "is-opened" classes on my end. Thanks!

Comment: This actually worked perfect. Thanks for giving me a straight forward solution and not a shitty reply like most people do on this site. cheers.

Comment: you're welcome! glad I was able to offer some help!